# [VsCode]: Is there any way to display the call heirarchy / call tree of C/C++ functions in Microsoft VsCode?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code, ide, code-navigation

I am looking for a suitable extension or any feature in VsCode that enables me to view call hierarchy / call tree of C/C++ functions. This is a super useful feature for all developers when it comes to understanding huge code-bases. I have been using Eclipse IDE for more than 10 years and recently switched to VsCode. And I find this feature in Eclipse helps in easier code navigation and understanding.
If there is any extension or keyboard shortcuts you are familiar with in VsCode, please point it out to me.

@TartanLlama Any idea, Sy?

Thank you in advance,
Honey